# Changing the value of a field of an object in couchdb map function

Tags: javascript, nosql, couchdb

In the map function of my view I am trying to change a field of a javascript object. Interestingly i can not change a field and than emit that object. 
I expect all the name fields if the irem object would be **"test"**. But i can`t change it. Any help would be great..
Map Function

```
function(doc) {
 doc.movieList.forEach(function(item){
      item.name = "test";
      emit([doc.companyId,item.movieID],item);
  });
}
```

Result

```
"rows": [
        {
            "key": [
                "147",
                "044a30f24e98660a8a8c12d09b1cafb3"
            ],
            "value": {
                "categoryID": 4,
                "dataModelVersion": 1,
                "forSale": false,
                "movieID": "044a30f24e98660a8a8c12d09b1cafb3",
                "name": "HULK",  //This field shoud be "test"
                "orderId": 99,
                "term": 0,
                "visible": true,
                "watchCount": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "147",
                "07c3c1bc4ac5d99286ccc54cde06b86a"
            ],
            "value": {
                "categoryID": 2,
                "dataModelVersion": 1,
                "forSale": false,
                "movieID": "07c3c1bc4ac5d99286ccc54cde06b86a",
                "name": "KACIS-PLANI", //This field shoud be "test"
                "orderId": 99,
                "term": 0,
                "visible": true,
                "watchCount": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "key": [
                "147",
                "0c6f28034e39bc94009be0375e2fba2a"
            ],
            "value": {
                "categoryID": 8,
                "dataModelVersion": 1,
                "forSale": false,
                "movieID": "0c6f28034e39bc94009be0375e2fba2a",
                "name": "YOLA-GELDIK", //This field shoud be "test"
                "orderId": 99,
                "term": 0,
                "visible": true,
                "watchCount": 0
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking into CouchDB [code](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/bf72d619d11d787c4cd5bf343d7dfeb4b16ef01a/share/server/views.js#L120), the doc provided to the map function is [sealed](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/seal) so no modification is allowed over the original object.

You need to copy the original object into a new one in order to modify its attributes.